# Lenovo e520 won't start with new hard disk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, lenovo

I use my e520 Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu since several years.

I bought a new hard disk (SEAGATE 2 TB Firecuda) and inserted into my laptop.

I booted via usb stick with an Ubuntu 17.04 iso and installed Ubuntu on my new internal hard disk.

Until here everything worked fine. I shut down the laptop, removed the usb stick and tried to boot.

But I only see the splash screen of Lenovo, but it hangs there.

I enabled "diagnostic" view in the bios, but still no error message or other hint to what could be wrong here.

Is the bios unable to access such a big hard disk (2 TByte)?

```
root@ubuntu:~# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E118E296-B60A-4D65-8729-98F0508AC202
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2157 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3907028991   1.8 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem
```

Comment: is the drive partitioned with GPT?

Comment: @ravery I added the gdisk output. ... Is the warning "found invalid ..." important?

Comment: are you booting EFI?

Comment: @ravery how can I influence "booting EFI"? In the bios there is "both". I switched to "legacy only" but this did not  help.

Comment: usually you can't disable EFI, just enable Legacy support.  Legacy boot requires a bootloader in the MBR and a flagged boot partition.  I'm not sure about size limits for Legacy boot. Repartitioning might help.If you want to install in EFI mode, repartition the disk as GPT. With a 2TB drive, GPT has advantages over MBR, but it requires EFI boot.

Comment: A UEFI boot needs an EFI partition (300M, FAT) for the bootloaders, on both GPT or MBR partitioned disks.  A legacy boot on a GPT disk requires a small (1M raw) grub-bios flagged partition for grub's core.img (it fits between the partitions on an MBR disk).  Lenovo may offer the choice of UEFI before legacy or legacy before UEFI in settings.

Comment: I found a solution. I wrote an answer. I don't understand why this is necessary. AFAIK these steps get done if you install ubuntu on the local hard disk...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get the new disk work.

I booted with the Ubuntu 17.04 iso via usb stick.

```
sudo bash
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt  # sda1 is the new installation which did not boot 
cd /mnt/
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount -t sysfs sys sys/
mount -o bind /dev dev/
chroot .
grub-install
update-grub
exit # exit chroot
reboot
```